# Push notifications with GCM - when to launch the IntentService?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the class `RegistrationIntentService` which extends `IntentService` and gets the device token inside `onHandleIntent`.

My question is, when should I start this service? If I just start it through `MainActivity` when the app launches, then onHandleIntent is not called. What and when is the proper way to start the intent?

Answer (score 0):

Have A look at [GCM's project MainActivty](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MainActivity.java) on GitHub , very Simple & Easy.

To be specific , you need to call `RegistrationIntentSerice` if `checkPlayServices()` is true ..

```
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

After declaring `checkPlayServices()` method you need to check if it's **true** and run the service:

```
if (checkPlayServices()) {
        // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
```

Comment: My implementation isn't that much different. I call `startService(intent)` from `MainActivity` but `onHandleIntent` is never called